# Is the freezing and lines on the iMac due to me breaking the LCD connector?

Tags: display, imac, startup

I have an iMac “Core i7” 2.8 27-Inch (Late 2009) that I replaced the hard drive in. Before I replaced the hard drive it wouldn’t boot fully in. The hard drive tests showed that the drive had bad sectors.

When ever I used a memtest, ultimate boot CD, or any Linux CD it would boot but the screen would go black when the video driver was loaded. I thought nothing of it.

When I replaced the hard drive I put too much force on the LCD connector on the board and it bent up off the board a bit. Darn.

I was able to get Mac OS back on. The display works, but as soon as it boots in a bit the screen gets lines and freezes. The system has 4 ram chips, which I’ve tried all independently and running memtester from a Linux boot disc says the RAM is okay. Although I still can’t get anything but a black screen when I boot into Linux (I SSH in to the Linux livecd).

In short:

1. The system always boots up to a black screen when using memtest, ultimate boot cd, and Linux live cds. But Mac installers work fine.
2. The memory seems fine.
3. It only freezes when booting into the installed MacOS.
4. The hard drive is now new and installs fine.

Would the lines be from the bent connector and is there any way to tell?
[image: The error]
[image: broken 1]
[image: broken 2]

Comment: A sure way to tell would be to replace the connector. Most probably the reason is the broken connector.

Comment: @jksoegaard I might just do that and post my findings. I'm not good at soldering. What part would I have to replace that ships with the connector?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the display data connector. You'll have to replace the entire logic board, if you do not want to solder anything.

Comment: @jksoegaard last question, sorry to harp on it. It’s bent off the board but only a bit. Is it possible that I still broke it even though it doesn’t look *that* bad? It’s definitely raised. I’ll add a picture.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check with a multimeter if there's a connection between each pin and the board (this is not however foolproof).

Comment: Remove all doubt.  Run [AHT](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) (Apple Hardware Test).  Boot from off while holding the D key.  Post the results.

Comment: @Allan it will not boot into AHT. I’ve tried with the installer USB plugged in, and without. Pressing and holding the D key won’t do much. The computer just restarts in a loop.

Comment: I cold boot holding the D key and it hangs on a completely grey screen for some time. Then I see the apple with the logo. Finally it tells me the computer rebooted because of a problem. Then it loops booting. Eventually it freezes with some sort of glitch on the screen (horizontal lines, one horizontal line on top, box on the bottom right etc).

Comment: Replaced the logic board but the issue persists no change. I didn't break the LCD connector this time. However, because I've been opening/closing it so much the vertical sync cable now needs to be replaced. But it'll still show video oddities when starting up and it won't boot into AHT. Not sure what's next.